# GCC on windows linux bash

Tags: c, linux, bash, gcc

I am using ubuntu through windows linux bash and it happens that I am trying to compile a file and I am getting this error:

```
"error: ‘for’ loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode".
```

But actually I would like not to use C99 mode but use C11 instead. How can I set my compiler to use C11 mode by default without having to pass any flags?

My GCC version is 4.8.4 running at ubuntu 14.04.3.

Thanks.

Comment: Use `-std=c11`.

Comment: @KerrekSB I know that it works but I would like to make it by default instead!

Comment: Recompile GCC to with the desired default.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `-std=c99` or `-std=gnu99` or higher to allow initial declarations in for loops. Or, just declare the variable first and use it in the for loop later.

For c11 of course, `-std=c11` is the way. I don't know of a way of setting this default and perhaps there is no way. But recent [*gcc* compilers *5.x* have c11 default](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/changes.html).

Comment: How can I update gcc to 5+ version? I tried sudo apt-get update but it seems to be updated.

Comment: Install a good distro like [Arch Linux](https://www.archlinux.org/) and forget about incompatible packages or similar issues with package managers.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to re-building GCC yourself (complicated and error prone), update GCC (newer GCCs may not be able to compile the kernel, The kernel-developers and the GCC-developers go not always, how shall I put it ... d'accord) and typing `-std=c11` every time, you can set an alias. Put the following line at the end of your `.bashrc`

```
alias gcc11="gcc -std=c11"
```

Let the shell re-read it's config file by `source ~/.bashrc` (If I remember Ubuntu correctly) and try it out.

You can call the alias `gcc`, too, but that might break 3rd-party makefiles.